# Pygame level/menu states

Tags: pygame

With my code below what would be the simplest and easiest way to implement game states to control levels? If I wanted to start with a title screen then load a level, and proceed to the next level on completion? If someone could explain the easiest way to handle this that would be great!

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

WIN_WIDTH = 1120 - 320
WIN_HEIGHT = 960 - 320
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 0
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30

def main():
    global level
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()
    level = 0

    bg = Surface((32,32))
    bg.convert()
    bg.fill(Color("#0094FF"))

    up = left = right = False
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32, 32)
    enemy = Enemy(32,32)
    platforms = []

    x = 0
    y = 0

    if level == 0:
        level = [
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                            ",
            "                                         E  ",
            "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            "               PPPPP        PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            "                            PPPP           P",
            "                            PPPP           P",
            "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "                      PPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "       PPPP                 PPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "PPPPP                       PPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "PPP         PPPPP           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
            "PPP                                     PPPP",
            "PPP                                     PPPP",
            "PPP                                     PPPP",
            "PPP                       PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            "PPP                       PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]

        #background = pygame.image.load("Untitled.png")


    total_level_width = len(level[0]) * 32
    total_level_height = len(level) * 32

    # build the level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            if col == "E":
                e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0

    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
    entities.add(player)
    entities.add(enemy)

    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit, "QUIT"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                raise SystemExit, "ESCAPE"

            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False

        # draw background
        for y in range(20):
            for x in range(25):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        # draw background
        #screen.blit(background, camera.apply((0,0)))
        #draw entities
        for e in entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))
        # update player, update camera, and refresh
        player.update(up, left, right, platforms)
        enemy.update(platforms)
        camera.update(player)
        pygame.display.flip()

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        try:
            return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)
        except AttributeError:
            return map(sum, zip(target, self.state.topleft))

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l + HALF_WIDTH, -t +HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling left
    l = max(-(camera.width - WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling right
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling bottom

    return Rect(l, t, w, h)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#0000FF"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(200, 1200, 32, 32)


    def update(self, up, left, right, platforms):
        if self.rect.top > 1440 or self.rect.top < 0:
            main()
        if self.rect.left > 1408 or self.rect.right < 0:
            main()
        if up:
            if self.onGround:
                self.yvel = 0
                self.yvel -= 10 # only jump if on the ground
        if left:
            self.xvel = -10
        if right:
            self.xvel = 10
        if not self.onGround:
            self.yvel += 0.3 # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            if self.yvel > 80: self.yvel = 80 # max falling speed
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0

        self.rect.left += self.xvel # increment in x direction
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms) # do x-axis collisions
        self.rect.top += self.yvel # increment in y direction
        self.onGround = False; # assuming we're in the air
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms) # do y-axis collisions

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0: self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0: self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom


class Enemy(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.yVel = 0
        self.xVel = 0
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#00FF00"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(300, 1200, 32, 32)
        self.onGround = False
        self.right_dis = False

    def update(self, platforms):
        if not self.onGround:
            self.yVel += 0.3

        if self.rect.left == 96:
            self.right_dis = False
        if self.rect.right == 480:
            self.right_dis = True
        if not self.right_dis:
            self.xVel = 2
        if self.right_dis:
            self.xVel = -2

        self.rect.left += self.xVel # increment in x direction
        self.collide(self.xVel, 0, platforms) # do x-axis collisions
        self.rect.top += self.yVel # increment in y direction
        self.onGround = False; # assuming we're in the air
        self.collide(0, self.yVel, platforms) # do y-axis collisions

    def collide(self, xVel, yVel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if xVel > 0: self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xVel < 0: self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yVel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                if yVel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom

class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        #self.image = Surface([32, 32], pygame.SRCALPHA, 32) #makes blocks invisible for much better artwork
        self.image = Surface((32,32)) #makes blocks visible for building levels
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("end.png")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Once you have a function to load a level, on the titlescreen clicking a button will do `load_map("level1")`. level1 will have a level win check, so on completion of that map to load the next map. `load_map("level2")` and so on.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

First of all, let's get rid of these ugly if-blocks:

```
for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit, "QUIT"
    if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
        raise SystemExit, "ESCAPE"

    if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
        up = True
    if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
        left = True
    if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
        right = True

    if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
        up = False
    if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
        left = False
    if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
        right = False
```

We can rewrite them as:

```
for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit, "QUIT"
    if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
        raise SystemExit, "ESCAPE"

pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
up, left, right = [pressed[key] for key in (K_UP, K_LEFT, K_RIGHT)]
```

This will come in handy later.

---

Back to topic: What we want is a bunch of different *Scenes*. Each *Scene* has to be responsible for its own rendering of the screen and event-handling.

Let's try to extract the existing code into a *game scene*, so that it will be possible to add other scenes later on. We start by creating an empty `Scene` class that will be the base class of our scenes:

```
class Scene(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def render(self, screen):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def update(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def handle_events(self, events):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Our plan is to overwrite each method in each sub-class, so we raise `NotImplementedError`s in the base class so we easily discover if we forget to do so (we could also use ABCs, but let's keep it simple).

Now let's put everything related to the running-game state (which is basically everything) into a new `GameScene` class.

```
class GameScene(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GameScene, self).__init__()
        level = 0
        self.bg = Surface((32,32))
        self.bg.convert()
        self.bg.fill(Color("#0094FF"))
        up = left = right = False
        self.entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(32, 32)
        self.enemy = Enemy(32,32)
        self.platforms = []

        x = 0
        y = 0

        if level == 0:
            level = [
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                            ",
                "                                         E  ",
                "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                "               PPPPP        PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                "                            PPPP           P",
                "                            PPPP           P",
                "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "                      PPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "       PPPP                 PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "PPPPP                       PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "PPP         PPPPP           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                "PPP                                     PPPP",
                "PPP                                     PPPP",
                "PPP                                     PPPP",
                "PPP                       PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                "PPP                       PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]

            #background = pygame.image.load("Untitled.png")


        total_level_width = len(level[0]) * 32
        total_level_height = len(level) * 32

        # build the level
        for row in level:
            for col in row:
                if col == "P":
                    p = Platform(x, y)
                    self.platforms.append(p)
                    self.entities.add(p)
                if col == "E":
                    e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                    self.platforms.append(e)
                    self.entities.add(e)
                x += 32
            y += 32
            x = 0

        self.camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
        self.entities.add(self.player)
        self.entities.add(self.enemy)

    def render(self, screen):
        for y in range(20):
            for x in range(25):
                screen.blit(self.bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        for e in self.entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, self.camera.apply(e))

    def update(self):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        up, left, right = [pressed[key] for key in (K_UP, K_LEFT, K_RIGHT)]
        self.player.update(up, left, right, self.platforms)
        self.enemy.update(self.platforms)
        self.camera.update(self.player)

    def handle_events(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pass #somehow go back to menu
```

Not perfect yet, but a good start. Everything related to the actual gameplay is extracted to its own class. Some variables have to be instance variable, so they have to be accessed via `self`.

Now we need to alter the `main`-function to actually use this class:

```
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True

    scene = GameScene()

    while running:
        timer.tick(60)

        if pygame.event.get(QUIT):
            running = False
            return
        scene.handle_events(pygame.event.get())
        scene.update()
        scene.render(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Note that I changed two little things: I use `pygame.event.get(QUIT)` to only get a possible `QUIT`-event first, since this is the only event that we are interesset in in our main-loop. All other events are passed directly to the current scene: `scene.handle_events(pygame.event.get())` .

At this point, we could think about extracting some classes to thier own files, but let's going on instead.

Let's create a title menu:

```
class TitleScene(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TitleScene, self).__init__()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 56)
        self.sfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 32)

    def render(self, screen):
        # beware: ugly! 
        screen.fill((0, 200, 0))
        text1 = self.font.render('Crazy Game', True, (255, 255, 255))
        text2 = self.sfont.render('> press space to start <', True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text1, (200, 50))
        screen.blit(text2, (200, 350))

    def update(self):
        pass

    def handle_events(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                self.manager.go_to(GameScene(0))
```

This just displays a green background and some text. If the player presses <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, we want to start the first level. Note this line:

```
self.manager.go_to(GameScene(0))
```

Here I pass the argument `0` to the `GameScene` class, so let's alter it so it accepts this parameter:

```
class GameScene(Scene):
    def __init__(self, level):
        ...
```

the line `level = 0` can be removed, as you already guessed.

So what it's `self.manager`? It's just a little helper class that manages the scenes for us.

```
class SceneMananger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.go_to(TitleScene())

    def go_to(self, scene):
        self.scene = scene
        self.scene.manager = self
```

It starts with the title scene and sets each scenes `manager` field to itself to allow the changing of the current scene. There are a lot of possibilities of how to implement such a scene manager, and this is the simpliest approach. A disadvantage is that each scene has to know which scene comes after it, but that should not bother us right now.

Let's use our new `SceneMananger`:

```
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True

    manager = SceneMananger()

    while running:
        timer.tick(60)

        if pygame.event.get(QUIT):
            running = False
            return
        manager.scene.handle_events(pygame.event.get())
        manager.scene.update()
        manager.scene.render(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

straightforward. Let's quickly add a second level and a winning/losing screen and we are done.

```
class CustomScene(object):

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 56)

    def render(self, screen):
        # ugly! 
        screen.fill((0, 200, 0))
        text1 = self.font.render(self.text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text1, (200, 50))

    def update(self):
        pass

    def handle_events(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == KEYDOWN:
                self.manager.go_to(TitleScene())
```

Below is the complete code. Note the changes to the `Player` class: instead of calling the `main` function again, it calls methods on the scene to indicate the player reached the exit or died.

Also, I changed the placement of the player and enemies. Now, you specify where the entity will appear in the level. E.g. `Player(5, 40)` will create the player at column 5, row 40 in the level. As a bonus, the enemies to proper collision detection.

I extracted the description of the levels to a dictionary named `levels`, so it will be easy to alter and add levels as needed (later, you probably want one file per level, so this is a good start). It could be extended to hold the player starting position, but you could also create a special tile, like `*` for starting position and `E` for enemy in the level description.

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

WIN_WIDTH = 1120 - 320
WIN_HEIGHT = 960 - 320
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 0
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30

levels = {0: {'level': [
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                         E  ",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "               PPPPP        PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                      PPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "       PPPP                 PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPP                       PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP         PPPPP           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                       PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                       PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",],
             'enemies': [(9, 38)]},
             1: {'level': [
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                            ",
                    "                                         E  ",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "               PPPPP        PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP           P",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                      PPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "       PPPP                 PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "                            PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPP                       PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                  PPPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                         PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP             PPPPPPPP    PPPP     PPPPPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP                                     PPPP",
                    "PPP          PPPPP                      PPPP",
                    "PPP          P            PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPP          P    PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
                    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",],
             'enemies': [(9, 38), (18, 38), (15, 15)]}}

class Scene(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def render(self, screen):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def update(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def handle_events(self, events):
        raise NotImplementedError

class GameScene(Scene):
    def __init__(self, levelno):
        super(GameScene, self).__init__()
        self.bg = Surface((32,32))
        self.bg.convert()
        self.bg.fill(Color("#0094FF"))
        up = left = right = False
        self.entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(5, 40)
        self.player.scene = self
        self.platforms = []

        self.levelno = levelno

        levelinfo = levels[levelno]
        self.enemies = [Enemy(*pos) for pos in levelinfo['enemies']]

        level = levelinfo['level']
        total_level_width = len(level[0]) * 32
        total_level_height = len(level) * 32

        # build the level
        x = 0
        y = 0
        for row in level:
            for col in row:
                if col == "P":
                    p = Platform(x, y)
                    self.platforms.append(p)
                    self.entities.add(p)
                if col == "E":
                    e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                    self.platforms.append(e)
                    self.entities.add(e)
                x += 32
            y += 32
            x = 0

        self.camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
        self.entities.add(self.player)
        for e in self.enemies:
            self.entities.add(e)

    def render(self, screen):
        for y in range(20):
            for x in range(25):
                screen.blit(self.bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        for e in self.entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, self.camera.apply(e))

    def update(self):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        up, left, right = [pressed[key] for key in (K_UP, K_LEFT, K_RIGHT)]
        self.player.update(up, left, right, self.platforms)

        for e in self.enemies:
            e.update(self.platforms)

        self.camera.update(self.player)

    def exit(self):
        if self.levelno+1 in levels:
            self.manager.go_to(GameScene(self.levelno+1))
        else:
            self.manager.go_to(CustomScene("You win!"))

    def die(self):
        self.manager.go_to(CustomScene("You lose!"))

    def handle_events(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                self.manager.go_to(TitleScene())

class CustomScene(object):

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 56)

    def render(self, screen):
        # ugly! 
        screen.fill((0, 200, 0))
        text1 = self.font.render(self.text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text1, (200, 50))

    def update(self):
        pass

    def handle_events(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == KEYDOWN:
                self.manager.go_to(TitleScene())

class TitleScene(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TitleScene, self).__init__()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 56)
        self.sfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 32)

    def render(self, screen):
        # ugly! 
        screen.fill((0, 200, 0))
        text1 = self.font.render('Crazy Game', True, (255, 255, 255))
        text2 = self.sfont.render('> press space to start <', True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text1, (200, 50))
        screen.blit(text2, (200, 350))

    def update(self):
        pass

    def handle_events(self, events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                self.manager.go_to(GameScene(0))

class SceneMananger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.go_to(TitleScene())

    def go_to(self, scene):
        self.scene = scene
        self.scene.manager = self

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True

    manager = SceneMananger()

    while running:
        timer.tick(60)

        if pygame.event.get(QUIT):
            running = False
            return
        manager.scene.handle_events(pygame.event.get())
        manager.scene.update()
        manager.scene.render(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        try:
            return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)
        except AttributeError:
            return map(sum, zip(target, self.state.topleft))

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l + HALF_WIDTH, -t +HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling left
    l = max(-(camera.width - WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling right
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling bottom

    return Rect(l, t, w, h)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#0000FF"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x*32, y*32, 32, 32)

    def update(self, up, left, right, platforms):
        if self.rect.top > 1440 or self.rect.top < 0:
            self.scene.die()
        if self.rect.left > 1408 or self.rect.right < 0:
            self.scene.die()
        if up:
            if self.onGround:
                self.yvel = 0
                self.yvel -= 10 # only jump if on the ground
        if left:
            self.xvel = -10
        if right:
            self.xvel = 10
        if not self.onGround:
            self.yvel += 0.3 # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            if self.yvel > 80: self.yvel = 80 # max falling speed
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0

        self.rect.left += self.xvel # increment in x direction
        if self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms): # do x-axis collisions
            self.rect.top += self.yvel # increment in y direction
            self.onGround = False; # assuming we're in the air
            self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms) # do y-axis collisions

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    self.scene.exit()
                    return False
                if xvel > 0: self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0: self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom
        return True

class Enemy(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.yVel = 0
        self.xVel = 2 # start moving immediately
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#00FF00"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x*32, y*32, 32, 32)
        self.onGround = False

    def update(self, platforms):
        if not self.onGround:
            self.yVel += 0.3

        # no need for right_dis to be a member of the class,
        # since we know we are moving right if self.xVel > 0
        right_dis = self.xVel > 0

        # create a point at our left (or right) feet 
        # to check if we reached the end of the platform
        m = (1, 1) if right_dis else (-1, 1)
        p = self.rect.bottomright if right_dis else self.rect.bottomleft
        fp = map(sum, zip(m, p))

        # if there's no platform in front of us, change the direction
        collide = any(p for p in platforms if p.rect.collidepoint(fp))
        if not collide:
            self.xVel *= -1

        self.rect.left += self.xVel # increment in x direction
        self.collide(self.xVel, 0, platforms) # do x-axis collisions
        self.rect.top += self.yVel # increment in y direction
        self.onGround = False; # assuming we're in the air
        self.collide(0, self.yVel, platforms) # do y-axis collisions

    def collide(self, xVel, yVel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if xVel > 0: 
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                    self.xVel *= -1 # hit wall, so change direction
                if xVel < 0: 
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                    self.xVel *= -1 # hit wall, so change direction
                if yVel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                if yVel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom

class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        #self.image = Surface([32, 32], pygame.SRCALPHA, 32) #makes blocks invisible for much better artwork
        self.image = Surface((32,32)) #makes blocks visible for building levels
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image = Surface((32,32)) #makes blocks visible for building levels
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is amazing helpful thank you for explaining things so in depth! This was truly extremely helpful and taught me a lot. I have one question about the collision detection you used for colliding with the walls, I could easily check for collision with player by checking for collision with the entities[] and if the collision is a player then do something, am I correct?

Comment: @user1758231 An easy way would be to take the `rect` of the player and use the [`Rect.collidelist`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.collidelist) to check if it collides with an enemy rect, something like `if self.player.rect.collidelist(e.rect for e in self.enemies) ...`

Answer (score 1):

I have also made a game in which I have a game menu, a levels menu, a loading part, and a playing part.
The way I did it was in the main game loop,
I went through a bunch of elif statements to determine what "mode" the game is in, and does the appropriate actions.
It seemed to work very well, and I suggest you try the same.

I realize My Code is really long, but if you go to where it says `#game loop` (use ctrl+f to find it), you can see the elifs to determine the mode.  Hope this helps.

```
#basic stuff
import pygame, sys, random
pygame.init()
window=pygame.display.set_mode((1500, 800), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
winrect=window.get_rect()

#colors
GREEN=(19, 225, 30)
BLUE=(41, 2, 245)
YELLOW=(251, 240, 32)
WHITE=(255, 255, 255)
BLACK=(0, 0, 0)
RED=(255, 0, 0)

#text
bigfont=pygame.font.SysFont('calibri', 75)
font=pygame.font.SysFont('calibri', 40)
texts={}

so=bigfont.render('Ball Bounce', True, BLUE)
rect=so.get_rect()
rect.top=winrect.top+100
rect.centerx=winrect.centerx
texts['title']=[so, rect]

so=font.render('Start', True, BLUE)
rect=so.get_rect()
so1=pygame.Surface((400, 50))
so2=pygame.Surface((400, 50))
rect1=so1.get_rect()
so1.fill(YELLOW)
so2.fill(RED)
pygame.draw.rect(so1, BLACK, rect1, 5)
pygame.draw.rect(so2, BLACK, rect1, 5)
rect.center=rect1.center
so1.blit(so, rect)
so2.blit(so, rect)
rect1.centerx=winrect.centerx
rect1.top=texts['title'][1].top+300
texts['start']=[so1, rect1, so2]

so=bigfont.render('Levels', True, BLUE)
rect=so.get_rect()
rect.centerx=winrect.centerx
rect.top=winrect.top+100
texts['levels']=[so, rect]

#levels [locked, unlocked, completed/mouseover, rect, state(locked, unlocked, completed)]
levels=[]
lock=pygame.image.load('images/lock.png').convert()
lock=pygame.transform.scale(lock, (100, 100))
lock.set_colorkey(lock.get_at((1, 1)))
for i in range(1, 21):
    so=pygame.Surface((100, 100))
    so.fill(YELLOW)
    rect=so.get_rect()
    pygame.draw.rect(so, BLACK, rect, 5)
    so1=pygame.Surface((100, 100))
    so1.fill(RED)
    pygame.draw.rect(so1, BLACK, rect, 5)
    text=font.render(str(i), True, BLUE)
    textrect=text.get_rect()
    textrect.center=rect.center
    so.blit(text, textrect)
    so1.blit(text, textrect)
    locked=pygame.Surface((100, 100))
    locked.blit(so, rect)
    locked.blit(lock, lock.get_rect())
    if i<=5:
        rect.top=texts['levels'][1].bottom+25
    elif i<=10:
        rect.top=levels[0][3].bottom+50
    elif i<=15:
        rect.top=levels[7][3].bottom+50
    else:
        rect.top=levels[12][3].bottom+50
    if i==1 or i==6 or i==11 or i==16:
        rect.right=winrect.centerx-200
    elif i==2 or i==7 or i==12 or i==17:
        rect.right=winrect.centerx-75
    elif i==3 or i==8 or i==13 or i==18:
        rect.centerx=winrect.centerx
    elif i==4 or i==9 or i==14 or i==19:
        rect.left=winrect.centerx+75
    else:
        rect.left=winrect.centerx+200
    if i==1:
        levels.append([locked, so, so1, rect, 1])
    else:
        levels.append([locked, so, so1, rect, 1])

#Wall class (0=horizontal, 1=vertical)
class cwall(pygame.Rect):
    'orientation (hor, vert), location, holesize, winrect'
    def __init__(self, orientation, location, holesize, winrect):
        self.orientation=orientation
        if orientation==0:
            self.height=5
            self.width=winrect.width
            self.centery=location
        if orientation==1:
            self.width=5
            self.height=winrect.height
            self.centerx=location
        self.holesize=holesize
        self.bbottomright=round(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[self.orientation]+self.holesize/2)
        self.ttopleft=round(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[self.orientation]-self.holesize/2)
    def update(self):
        self.bbottomright=round(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[self.orientation]+self.holesize/2)
        self.ttopleft=round(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[self.orientation]-self.holesize/2)
        if self.bbottomright<self.holesize:
            self.bbottomright=self.holesize
        if self.ttopleft>self.right-self.holesize and self.orientation==0:
            self.ttopleft=self.right-self.holesize
        if self.ttopleft>self.bottom-self.holesize and self.orientation==1:
            self.ttopleft=self.bottom-self.holesize

#Ball Class
class cball(pygame.Rect):
    'diameter, speed, color, winrect'
    def __init__(self, diameter, speed, color, winrect):
        self.width=diameter
        self.height=diameter
        self.speed=speed
        self.color=color
        self.direction=random.randint(1, 4)
        self.center=(random.randint(round(diameter/2), round(winrect.right-diameter/2)), random.randint(round(diameter/2), round(winrect.bottom-diameter/2)))
    def update(self, winrect, walls):
        if self.direction/2==round(self.direction/2):
            self.right+=self.speed
        else:
            self.right-=self.speed
        if self.direction<=2:
            self.top+=self.speed
        else:
            self.top-=self.speed
        for wall in walls:
            if wall.collidepoint(self.center):
                if wall.orientation==0 and (self.centerx<wall.ttopleft or self.centerx>wall.bbottomright):
                    if self.direction==1:
                        self.direction=3
                        self.bottom=wall.top
                    elif self.direction==2:
                        self.direction=4
                        self.bottom=wall.top
                    elif self.direction==3:
                        self.direction=1
                        self.top=wall.bottom
                    else:
                        self.direction=2
                        self.top=wall.bottom
                elif wall.orientation==1 and (self.centery<wall.ttopleft or self.centery>wall.bbottomright):
                    if self.direction==1:
                        self.direction=2
                        self.left=wall.right
                    elif self.direction==2:
                        self.direction=1
                        self.right=wall.left
                    elif self.direction==3:
                        self.direction=4
                        self.left=wall.right
                    else:
                        self.direction=3
                        self.right=wall.left
            elif wall.orientation==0:
                if self.bottom>wall.top and self.centery<wall.top and (self.centerx<wall.ttopleft or self.centerx>wall.bbottomright):
                    if self.direction==1:
                        self.direction=3
                        self.bottom=wall.top
                    elif self.direction==2:
                        self.direction=4
                        self.bottom=wall.top
                elif self.top<wall.bottom and self.centery>wall.bottom and (self.centerx<wall.ttopleft or self.centerx>wall.bbottomright):
                    if self.direction==3:
                        self.direction=1
                        self.top=wall.bottom
                    if self.direction==4:
                        self.direction=2
                        self.top=wall.bottom
            else:
                if self.left<wall.right and self.centerx>wall.right and (self.centery<wall.ttopleft or self.centery>wall.bbottomright):
                    if self.direction==1:
                        self.direction=2
                        self.left=wall.right
                    elif self.direction==3:
                        self.direction=4
                        self.left=wall.right
                elif self.right>wall.left and self.centerx<wall.left and (self.centery<wall.ttopleft or self.centery>wall.bbottomright):
                    if self.direction==2:
                        self.direction=1
                        self.right=wall.left
                    if self.direction==4:
                        self.direction=3
                        self.right=wall.left
        if self.top<0:
            if self.direction==3:
                self.direction=1
                self.top=0
            elif self.direction==4:
                self.direction=2
                self.topn=0
        if self.bottom>winrect.bottom:
            if self.direction==1:
                self.direction=3
                self.bottom=winrect.bottom
            elif self.direction==2:
                self.direction=4
                self.bottom=winrect.bottom
        if self.left<0:
            if self.direction==1:
                self.direction=2
                self.left=0
            elif self.direction==3:
                self.direction=4
                self.left=0
        if self.right>winrect.right:
            if self.direction==2:
                self.direction=1
                self.right=winrect.right
            if self.direction==4:
                self.direction=3
                self.right=winrect.right
        for box in boxes:
            if box[0].collidepoint(self.center) and self.color==box[1]:
                return True
        return False

#Game loop setup
mode='title'

#Game loop
while True:
    if mode=='title':
        #event loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if texts['start'][1].collidepoint(event.pos):
                    mode='levels'
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
        #screen update
        window.fill(GREEN)
        mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if texts['start'][1].collidepoint(mouse):
            window.blit(texts['start'][2], texts['start'][1])
        else:
            window.blit(texts['start'][0], texts['start'][1])
        window.blit(texts['title'][0], texts['title'][1])
        pygame.display.update()

    elif mode=='levels':
        #event loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for level in levels:
                    if level[3].collidepoint(event.pos) and level[4]!=0:
                        mode='loading'
                        loadinglevel=levels.index(level)+1
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
        #screen update
        window.fill(GREEN)
        for level in levels:
            if level[3].collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and level[4]==1:
                window.blit(level[2], level[3])
            else:
                window.blit(level[level[4]], level[3])
        window.blit(texts['levels'][0], texts['levels'][1])
        pygame.display.update()

    elif mode=='loading':
        if loadinglevel==1:
            walls=[cwall(1, winrect.width/2, 100, winrect)]
            balls=[]
            for i in range(2):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, GREEN, winrect))
            for i in range(2):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, YELLOW, winrect))
            boxes=((pygame.Rect(0, 0, round(winrect.width/2), winrect.height), GREEN), (pygame.Rect(round(winrect.width/2), 0, round(winrect.width/2), winrect.height), YELLOW))
        elif loadinglevel==2:
            walls=[cwall(1, winrect.width/2, 100, winrect)]
            balls=[]
            for i in range(4):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, GREEN, winrect))
            for i in range(4):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, YELLOW, winrect))
            boxes=((pygame.Rect(0, 0, round(winrect.width/2), winrect.height), GREEN), (pygame.Rect(round(winrect.width/2), 0, round(winrect.width/2), winrect.height), YELLOW))
        elif loadinglevel==3:
            walls=[cwall(1, winrect.width/3, 100, winrect), cwall(1, 2*winrect.width/3, 100, winrect)]
            balls=[]
            for i in range(2):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, GREEN, winrect))
            for i in range(2):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, YELLOW, winrect))
            for i in range(2):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, BLUE, winrect))
            boxes=((pygame.Rect(0, 0, round(winrect.width/3), winrect.height), GREEN), (pygame.Rect(round(winrect.width/3), 0, round(winrect.width/3), winrect.height), YELLOW),
                   (pygame.Rect(round(2*winrect.width/3), 0, round(winrect.width/3), winrect.height), BLUE))
        elif loadinglevel==4:
            walls=[cwall(1, winrect.width/3, 100, winrect), cwall(1, 2*winrect.width/3, 100, winrect)]
            balls=[]
            for i in range(4):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, GREEN, winrect))
            for i in range(4):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, YELLOW, winrect))
            for i in range(4):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, BLUE, winrect))
            boxes=((pygame.Rect(0, 0, round(winrect.width/3), winrect.height), GREEN), (pygame.Rect(round(winrect.width/3), 0, round(winrect.width/3), winrect.height), YELLOW),
                   (pygame.Rect(round(2*winrect.width/3), 0, round(winrect.width/3), winrect.height), BLUE))

        elif loadinglevel==7:
            walls=[cwall(1, winrect.width/2, 100, winrect), cwall(0, winrect.height/2, 100, winrect)]
            balls=[]
            for i in range(2):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, GREEN, winrect))
            for i in range(2):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, YELLOW, winrect))
            for i in range(2):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, BLUE, winrect))
            for i in range(2):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, RED, winrect))
            boxes=((pygame.Rect(0, 0, round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2)), GREEN),
                   (pygame.Rect(0, round(winrect.height/2), round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2)), RED),
                   (pygame.Rect(round(winrect.width/2), 0, round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2)), YELLOW),
                   (pygame.Rect(round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2),  round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2)), BLUE))
        elif loadinglevel==8:
            walls=[cwall(1, winrect.width/2, 100, winrect), cwall(0, winrect.height/2, 100, winrect)]
            balls=[]
            for i in range(4):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, GREEN, winrect))
            for i in range(4):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, YELLOW, winrect))
            for i in range(4):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, BLUE, winrect))
            for i in range(4):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, RED, winrect))
            boxes=((pygame.Rect(0, 0, round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2)), GREEN),
                   (pygame.Rect(0, round(winrect.height/2), round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2)), RED),
                   (pygame.Rect(round(winrect.width/2), 0, round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2)), YELLOW),
                   (pygame.Rect(round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2),  round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2)), BLUE))
        elif loadinglevel==5:
            walls=[cwall(1, winrect.width/2, 100, winrect), cwall(0, winrect.height/2, 100, winrect)]
            balls=[]
            for i in range(10):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, RED, winrect))
            boxes=((pygame.Rect(0, 0, round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2)), RED),
                   (pygame.Rect(0, round(winrect.height/2), winrect.width, round(winrect.height/2)), WHITE),
                   (pygame.Rect(round(winrect.width/2), 0, round(winrect.width/2), winrect.height), WHITE))
        elif loadinglevel==6:
            walls=[cwall(1, winrect.width/2, 100, winrect), cwall(0, winrect.height/2, 100, winrect)]
            balls=[]
            for i in range(20):
                balls.append(cball(20, 3, RED, winrect))
            boxes=((pygame.Rect(0, 0, round(winrect.width/2), round(winrect.height/2)), RED),
                   (pygame.Rect(0, round(winrect.height/2), winrect.width, round(winrect.height/2)), WHITE),
                   (pygame.Rect(round(winrect.width/2), 0, round(winrect.width/2), winrect.height), WHITE))
        mode='playing'
    elif mode=='playing':
        while True:
            #event loop
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key==pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
            #updates
            updates=[]
            for wall in walls:
                wall.update()
            for ball in balls:
                updates.append(ball.update(winrect, walls))
            #Seeing if won
            won=True
            for update in updates:
                if not update:
                    won=False
                    break
            if won:
                if levels[loadinglevel][4]==0:
                    levels[loadinglevel][4]=1
                levels[loadinglevel-1][4]=2
                mode='levels'
                break
            #blitting
            window.fill(WHITE)
            for box in boxes:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, box[1], box[0])
            for wall in walls:
                if wall.orientation==0:
                    pygame.draw.rect(window, BLACK, (wall.left, wall.top, wall.ttopleft, wall.height))
                    pygame.draw.rect(window, BLACK, (wall.bbottomright, wall.top, wall.right-wall.bbottomright, wall.height))
                else:
                    pygame.draw.rect(window, BLACK, (wall.left, wall.top, wall.width, wall.ttopleft))
                    pygame.draw.rect(window, BLACK, (wall.left, wall.bbottomright, wall.width, wall.bottom-wall.holesize))
            for ball in balls:
                pygame.draw.circle(window, ball.color, ball.center, round(ball.width/2))
                pygame.draw.circle(window, BLACK, ball.center, round(ball.width/2), 2)
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(100)
```

Comment: i would suggest to put your level loading in seperate functions, to improve readability

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski That would probably help, but I made the code without knowing it would answer this question, and I don't feel like changing it now.

Comment: it's just some advice for future :)