# Scenes with Pygame - how to create

Tags: pygame

I want to create two separate scenes (menu and game) in my program, but not really sure how to go about it. Should I create screen outside of main loop or maybe within menu class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pygame level/menu states](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700889/pygame-level-menu-states)

Answer (score 0):

I would do scenes as two separated classes with own `mainloop`.

I can use `menu` as main class and create `screen` before mainloop in `menu` and in `mainloop` I can `game(screen)`.

I can create class `app` (with `screen` created before its `mainloop`) which calls `menu(screen)` or `game(screen)` (or other scenes). When player (during game) want to go to `menu` or `options` or `help` it returns to `app` and `app` calls `menu(screen)` or `options(screen)` or `help(screen)`.

Answer (score -1):

Use some sort of flag such as :

```
while True:
    if status = "menu": status = show_menu()
    elif status = "game": status = run_game()
    elif blah blah...
```

Have some code to return the appropriate status, like if game is selected from menu return "game".