# Getting rid of recursion in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I made a game in pygame which involves main menu, game loop, victory screen and crash screen. My game works how I want it to work, but I know everytime I change a screen, I am just going deeper into the loop and game can crash when i reach 1000 recursions (I think so?)). I don't know how to fix it, so if you could please Help me.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import sys


pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
screen_width, screen_height = 1200, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
BLUE = pygame.Color('dodgerblue3')
ORANGE = pygame.Color('sienna3')
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (13, 255, 0)
YELLOW = (0, 255, 20)
BRIGHT_YELLOW = (255, 255, 20)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
frame_rate = 60
last_seconds = None

class Walls(pygame.Rect):

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        super().__init__(x, y, w, h)


class LeftRedRect(pygame.Rect):

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, vel):
        # Calling the __init__ method of the parent class
        super().__init__(x, y, w, h)
        self.vel = vel

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.vel  # Moving
        if self.right > 600 or self.left < 320:  # If it's not in this area
            self.vel = -self.vel  # Inverting the direction


class RightRedRect(pygame.Rect):

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, vel):
        super().__init__(x, y, w, h)
        self.vel = vel

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.vel
        if self.right > 1180 or self.left < 620:
            self.vel = -self.vel


class UpAndDownRedRect(pygame.Rect):

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, vel):
        super().__init__(x, y, w, h)
        self.vel = vel

    def update(self):
        self.y += self.vel
        if self.top < 20 or self.bottom > 535:
            self.vel = -self.vel


def quit_game():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font(None, 115)
    screen.blit(largeText.render(text, True, BLUE), (370, 250))
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.wait(1500)

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action = None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()


    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h  > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action is not None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x, y, w, h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",35)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)))
    screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def restart():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit_game()

        screen.fill(WHITE)

        largeText = pygame.font.Font(None, 115)
        screen.blit(largeText.render("You lost", True, BLUE), (420, 50))

        button("Restart", 525, 250, 150, 60, BRIGHT_YELLOW, YELLOW, menu)
        button("Quit", 525, 350, 150, 60, BRIGHT_YELLOW, YELLOW, quit_game)

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

def victory_screen():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit_game()

        screen.fill(WHITE)

        #TO DO: POSITION THE TEXT#
        largeText = pygame.font.Font(None, 115)
        screen.blit(largeText.render("Congratulations!", True, BLUE), (300, 50))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font(None, 60)
        screen.blit(largeText.render("You beat the game!", True, BLUE), (400, 150))

        button("Restart", 525, 250, 150, 60, BRIGHT_YELLOW, YELLOW, menu)
        button("Quit", 525, 350, 150, 60, BRIGHT_YELLOW, YELLOW, quit_game)

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(frame_rate)

def front_page():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit_game()

        screen.fill(WHITE)

        largeText = pygame.font.Font(None, 115)
        screen.blit(largeText.render("My Game", True, BLUE), (430, 50))

        button("Start", 525, 250, 150, 60, BRIGHT_YELLOW, YELLOW, menu)
        button("Quit", 525, 350, 150, 60, BRIGHT_YELLOW, YELLOW, quit_game)

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(frame_rate)


def menu():
    vel = 4
    vel_left = 5
    vel_right = -5
    vel_up = 7

    player = pygame.Rect(40, 45, 30, 30)

    finish_line = pygame.Rect(620, 535, 560, 45)

    walls = [
        Walls(0, 0, 1200, 20), Walls(0, 0, 20, 600),
        Walls(0, 580, 1200, 20), Walls(1180, 0, 20, 600),
        Walls(300, 0, 20, 530), Walls(20, 100, 230, 20),
        Walls(70, 200, 230, 20), Walls(20, 300, 230, 20),
        Walls(70, 400, 230, 20), Walls(600, 100, 20, 500)
    ]

    leftredrects = [
        LeftRedRect(320, 120, 30, 30, vel_left),
        LeftRedRect(320, 240, 30, 30, vel_left),
        LeftRedRect(320, 360, 30, 30, vel_left),
        LeftRedRect(570, 180, 30, 30, vel_right),
        LeftRedRect(570, 300, 30, 30, vel_right),
        LeftRedRect(570, 420, 30, 30, vel_right)
    ]

    rightredrects = [
        RightRedRect(1140, 120, 30, 30, vel_left),
        RightRedRect(1140, 240, 30, 30, vel_left),
        RightRedRect(1140, 360, 30, 30, vel_left),
        RightRedRect(620, 180, 30, 30, vel_right),
        RightRedRect(620, 300, 30, 30, vel_right),
        RightRedRect(620, 420, 30, 30, vel_right),
    ]

    upanddownredrects = [
        UpAndDownRedRect(620, 20, 30, 30, vel_up),
        UpAndDownRedRect(752, 505, 30, 30, vel_up),
        UpAndDownRedRect(885, 20, 30, 30, vel_up),
        UpAndDownRedRect(1016, 505, 30, 30, vel_up),
        UpAndDownRedRect(1150, 20, 30, 30, vel_up)
    ]

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit_game()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # Player coordinates
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.x > 0:
            player.x -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.x < 1200 - player.width:
            player.x += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and player.y > 0:
            player.y -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player.y < 600 - player.height:
            player.y += vel

        # Game logic
        for wall in walls:
            # Check if the player rectangle collides with a wall rectangle
            if player.colliderect(wall):
                print("Game over")
               # message_display("Game Over")
               # restart()

        for rect in rightredrects:
            rect.update()  # Movement and bounds checking
            if player.colliderect(rect):
                print("Game over")
               # message_display("Game Over")
               # restart()

        for rect in leftredrects:
            rect.update()
            if player.colliderect(rect):
                print("Game over")
               # message_display("Game Over")
                #restart()

        for rect in upanddownredrects:
            rect.update()
            if player.colliderect(rect):
                print("Game over")
                #message_display("Game Over")
                #restart()

        if player.colliderect(finish_line):
            print("You beat the game")
            victory_screen()

        # Drawing everything
        screen.fill(WHITE)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BRIGHT_YELLOW, finish_line)

        for wall in walls:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, wall)

        for rect in rightredrects:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rect)

        for rect in leftredrects:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rect)

        for rect in upanddownredrects:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rect)


        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, player)

        pygame.display.update()

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(frame_rate)


def main():
    scene = front_page  # Set the current scene.
    while scene is not None:
        # Execute the current scene function. When it's done
        # it returns either the next scene or None which we
        # assign to the scene variable.
        scene = scene()


main()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: In addition to skrx' answer, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700889/pygame-level-menu-states/14727074#14727074)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `next_scene` variable to your scene and set it to the next scene function when the button gets pressed. In the while loop you would have to check `if next_scene is not None:` and then return the `next_scene` to the `main` function where it will be called. It would be necessary to define nested callback functions to change the `next_scene` variable.

```
def front_page():
    next_scene = None

    def start_game():
        nonlocal next_scene
        # Set the `next_scene` variable in the enclosing scope
        # to the `menu` function.
        next_scene = menu

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit_game()

        # Return the next scene to the `main` function if the variable is not None.
        if next_scene is not None:
            return next_scene

        screen.fill(WHITE)

        button("Start", 525, 250, 150, 60, BRIGHT_YELLOW, YELLOW, start_game)
        button("Quit", 525, 350, 150, 60, BRIGHT_YELLOW, YELLOW, quit_game)

        pygame.display.flip()  # Don't call both display.update and display.flip.
        clock.tick(60)
```

In the `menu` function you can just return the `restart` function when the player touches a wall or a moving rect:

```
for wall in walls:
    # Check if the player rectangle collides with a wall rectangle
    if player.colliderect(wall):
        print("Game over")
        return restart
```

Comment: How do I check if there will be no more recursion errors? Because I wrote what u did in front_page() function and next_scene and start_game() are appearing gray... Do I have to write that in the other scenes or? I am not quite sure if I understood this correctly.

Comment: I am sorry, actually everything is good, I just didn't change my button, I can't even copy the code lol i suck

Answer (score 1):

> for every place where you print('Game over') return True like i did in this part of your code:

```
        for wall in walls:
        # Check if the player rectangle collides with a wall rectangle
        if player.colliderect(wall):
            print("Game over")
            return True
```

if you dont the game is still in the while loop and it will print "game over" until you can cook eggs on your computer or it crashes.